# Using bindBidirectional() method for StyleClass

Tags: javafx-2

I need to make next dependency between two TextFields: when I click on any of them, they both change their styles.

I've tried to make it like this:

```
    tb2.styleProperty().bindBidirectional(tb1.styleProperty());
    tb1.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            System.out.println(tb1.styleProperty().toString());
            System.out.println(tb2.styleProperty().toString());
            tb1.getStyleClass().clear();
            tb1.getStyleClass().add("green");
            System.out.println(tb1.styleProperty().toString());
            System.out.println(tb2.styleProperty().toString());
        }
    });
```

But it does not work: tb1 changes its style after clicking, but tb2 does not;
Also, systemouts shows that styles are not equal:

```
StringProperty [bean: TextField[id=tb1, styleClass=green], name: style, value: ]
StringProperty [bean: TextField[id=tb2, styleClass=text-input text-field], name: style, value: ]
StringProperty [bean: TextField[id=tb1, styleClass=green], name: style, value: ]
StringProperty [bean: TextField[id=tb2, styleClass=text-input text-field], name: style, value: ]
```

Also, i've tried to bind their text Property, and it works (when i change text in one of my TextFields, text in the other one changes too):

```
tb2.textProperty().bindBidirectional(tb1.textProperty());
```

So, what am i doing wrong with Style Property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Style` and `StyleClass` are two different properties. `Style` includes `;` separated `property:value` pairs while `StyleClass` includes list of CSS selectors defined in CSS file. In your handler if you try something like

```
tb1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
```

instead of

```
tb1.getStyleClass().clear();
tb1.getStyleClass().add("green");
```

you will see that the `tb2`'s background color will change as well. To accomplish your task try adding list change listener to styleClass observable list.

Comment: Sooo... It looks like there is no way to apply and bind not Style, but StyleClass (it looks like there is no StyleClass property for TextField)?

Comment: @AgafonovaVictoria Yes it seems the StyleClass is not bindable.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve style binding this way:

```
SimpleStringProperty dynamicProperty = new SimpleStringProperty("-fx-background-color: " +     "#d6d6d6");
Text title = new Text("Test");
title.setId("textID");
dynamicProperty.bindBidirectional(title.styleProperty());
```

When the setValue() method is called on the dynamicProperty object, it updates the Text object's style property.  I propose you do a bidirectional bind on both objects (tb1, tb2).

```
SimpleStringProperty dynamicProperty = new SimpleStringProperty("-fx-background-color: " + "#d6d6d6");
dynamicProperty.bindBidirectional(tb1.styleProperty());
dynamicProperty.bindBidirectional(tb2.styleProperty());
```